# Avoid showing values in url while using Jquery ajax in cakephp

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "../users/registration",
          data: 'username='+ username  + '&password='+ password +  '&email='+ email,
          success : function(data) {
              alert(data);}

          });
```

On the action it shows
//localhost/survey/users/**registration?username=dfdf&password=sdfdsfd&rpass=dfddd&email=dfdfdd&submitted=true**

How to avoid this?

My controller function

```
if (!empty($this->data)) 
    {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {


            $this->flash('Registration Successful','/users/register');

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the bottom where it shows examples:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You'll see how they send their "data".  You are sending it via URL parameters with &, and ?...etc

Comment: Any suggestions to avoid this situation. For some time I have no touch on this. But I had used it...But I am never getting a situation like this. Or I forgot something..

Comment: Moreover I used post method

Comment: You are almost literally making no sense.  You didn't follow the examples on the API page for jQuery ajax(), and you specifically pass it URL parameters, then wonder why they're showing up...  Use serialize() or json data `{key:value}`, not `?something=Something`.  And then you down-vote the only person trying to help you...